# Calculating date difference with angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

I needed to be able to calculate the difference between two days, inclusive, and display the difference. Ideally this would be via an angular filter so it can be used all over the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JS Filter

```
generalFilters.filter('dateDiff', function () {
  var magicNumber = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

  return function (toDate, fromDate) {
    if(toDate && fromDate){
      var dayDiff = Math.floor((toDate - fromDate) / magicNumber);
      if (angular.isNumber(dayDiff)){
        return dayDiff + 1;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

HTML to display the value.

```
<div class="field-value">{{entry.toStr | dateDiff:entry.fromStr}} <ng-pluralize count="entry.toStr | dateDiff:entry.fromStr" when="{1:'Day', other: 'Days'}"></ng-pluralize></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [26649194](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649194/calculating-days-difference-with-using-angular-and-jquery-datepicker/32895495#32895495)

[angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) does the trick! ...and (very) else more.

Using the **amDifference** filter:

> Get the difference between two dates in milliseconds. Parameters are
>   date, units and usePrecision. Date defaults to current date. Example:

```
<span>Difference: {{ dateFrom | amDifference : dateTo : 'days' }} days</span>
```

Comment: Please don't post essentially the same answer across multiple questions. You should post the answer to the best question and then flag the other questions as duplicates of the first question if they are indeed duplicates. If they are not duplicates then you need to adjust your answers so that they are answering the question asked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new of stack overflow. I was looking for a way to flag as duplicate with no success. Could u please tell me how to do it? Thank u

Comment: You can flag any post when you have at least 15 reputation, but flagging as duplicate requires 50 reputation, because you also need the comment priviledge for that.

Comment: So I can't... That's what I was afraid... What do I have to do now?

Comment: Wait until you can flag as duplicate or help me identify the best question that all of them should be duplicates of so I can vote to close as duplicate. They probably won't be closed, because those are old questions, but at least a comment will be created.