# Calculating days difference with using angular and jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

In angular, I am trying to calculate the number of days between two selected date with using jQuery datepicker. It returns only null with the function that I am using..

However I am not quite sure if it is the function or using datepicker in angular..It looks like the problem is function but it works when I use it with jQuery..

my function:

```
$scope.dayDiff = function(firstDate,secondDate){

    $scope.dayDifference = parseInt(Math.round((secondDate - firstDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));;
}
```

the rest: http://jsfiddle.net/1mzgLywe/5/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to subtract strings, this will not work. `secondDate` and `firstDate` are type of string not Date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is the working fiddle please check , [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykhbf26u/2/)

create a function for get the dateString to pass into `new Date()`

```
$scope.formatString = function(format) {
    var day   = parseInt(format.substring(0,2));
    var month  = parseInt(format.substring(3,5));
    var year   = parseInt(format.substring(6,10));
    var date = new Date(year, month-1, day);
    return date;
}
```

modify the `dayDiff` function as below,

```
$scope.dayDiff = function(firstDate,secondDate){
    var date2 = new Date($scope.formatString(secondDate));
    var date1 = new Date($scope.formatString(firstDate));
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());   
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    alert(diffDays);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) does the trick! ...and (very) else more.

Using the **amDifference** filter:

> Get the difference between two dates in milliseconds. Parameters are
>   date, units and usePrecision. Date defaults to current date. Example:

```
<span>Difference: {{ dateFrom | amDifference : dateTo : 'days' }} days</span>
```