# How to subtract a date from current date in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date, controller

I am trying to calculate experience of an employee in my application. I was planning to do so by subtracting 'careerStartedOn' from the 'Current date'.

Here's my code for controller :

```
myApp.controller('getAllBenchersController', ['$scope', 'employeeTalentPoolServices', 'dataTable', '$window', '$timeout', function ($scope, employeeTalentPoolServices, dataTable, $window, $timeout) {
    employeeTalentPoolServices.getAllBenchers().then(function (result) {
     var mainData = result.data;
        $scope.date = new Date();
         $scope.blockEmployee = function (id) {

            employeeTalentPoolServices.blockEmployee(id);
            $scope.showhide = false;
        }
         });

    employeeTalentPoolServices.getCustomerAccounts().then(function (result) {
        $scope.accountData = result.data;
        });

}]);
```

Html :

```
<div class="widget-content table-container" ng-controller="getAllBenchersController">
<table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in data">
      <td data-title="'Experience'" sortable="'Experience'" filter="{ 'account': 'text' }">
                         {{employee.careerStartedOn | date:myApp.dateFormat}}
                        </td>
    </tr>
                </table>
```

in HTML, if i call `{{employee.careerStartedOn | date:myApp.dateFormat}}` i will get the 'careerStartedOn' date and when i call `{{date | date:myApp.dateFormat}}` i will get the current date.

I need to substract the **careerStartedOn** date from the current **date** and then display it in the `<td>`. I am a fresher and cant find a solution to do this.

Can anyone help me out with the code to achieve this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944750/how-to-subtract-date-time-in-javascript

Comment: what you want to display? and you can use `moment.js` for this

Comment: I want to display the result of the calulation (CurrentDate - CareerStartedOn . The difference should be in no of years/months

Comment: @DanielShillcock - Its using javascript in the post you mentioned. I want to know how to achieve that in AngularJS with the controller.

Comment: @pro.mean -  I want to display the result of the calulation (CurrentDate - CareerStartedOn . The difference should be in no of years/months. Can you show me an example of how to achieve this using moment.js? I am not sure where to do it. In the controller or in HTML?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649194/calculating-days-difference-with-using-angular-and-jquery-datepicker). This may be useful to you.

Comment: @Nishant123 - In the example, they are reading values using date time picker. What I want is to fetch the date from API and substract it from current date and display it in number of years/ months(not in number of days).

Comment: @Phoenix Can you please share your date format

Comment: @Phoenix I have added an answer. Please see if that helps you

Comment: I will check on that now @Nishant123....

My date format on 'careerStartedOn' is '2016-10-03T13:44:00.587'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to calculate experience in years/months

```
$scope.CalDate = function(date1,date2) {
    var diff = Math.floor(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
    var secs = Math.floor(diff/1000);
    var mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
    var hours = Math.floor(mins/60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours/24);
    var months = Math.floor(days/31);
    var years = Math.floor(months/12);
    months=Math.floor(months%12);
    days = Math.floor(days%31);
    hours = Math.floor(hours%24);
    mins = Math.floor(mins%60);
    secs = Math.floor(secs%60); 
    var message = ""; 
    if(days<=0){
    message += secs + " sec "; 
    message += mins + " min "; 
    message += hours + " hours "; 
    }else{
            if(years>0){
            message += years + " years ";    
        }
        if(months>0 || years>0){
            message += months + " months ";
        }
        message += days + " days";
    }
    return message
};


$scope.getExp = function(date)
{
    date = new Date($filter('date')(date, "yyyy/MM/dd"));
  var currdate = new Date($filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy/MM/dd"));

  var exp = $scope.CalDate(currdate,date);
  return exp;
}
```

HTML

```
<table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
 <th>
   <tr>
     <td>Career Started On</td>
     <td align="center">Experience</td>
   </tr>
 </th>
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in data">
  <td>
     {{employee.careerStartedOn | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd'}}
   </td>
   <td align="center">
   {{getExp(employee.careerStartedOn)}}
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you don't need days to be displayed you can remove this line

```
message += days + " days";
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/6t3b9mzy/4/)**

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript)

Comment: My date format in 'careerStartedOn' is '2016-10-03T13:44:00.587'.  Also you are hardcoding the date in the function. How can I take it from my API {{employee.careerStartedOn}}

Comment: `date` filter formats `date object` into a `string`. You need to convert it back to `date object` by `new Date("YOUR STRING DATE")`. So whatever date you are getting from `employee.careerStartedOn` after applying `date filter` pass that formated date to `new Date("PASS IT HERE")`. And use the CalDate() to calculate experience

Comment: Okay but as I am still in learning phase, I am not sure how to do it. Can you please show it in your answer? Tnx

Comment: @Phoenix I have updated my answer. I have taken a dummy `data array` with some values in it. Please see the updated link also

Comment: $scope.getExp = function (date) {
is getting the value (date = "2016-10-03T13:44:00.587). After that it is not executing the statement : var currdate = new Date($filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy/MM/dd"));

Comment: Add `'$filter'` service to your controller

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below in your HTML to display experience in terms of number of years

```
           <tr ng-repeat="employee in data">
  <td data-title="'Experience'" sortable="'Experience'" filter="{ 'account': 'text' }">
                     {{getExp(employee.careerStartedOn)}}
                    </td>
```

In your JS

```
    $scope.getExp = function(str) {
    var today = new Date();
    var startDate = new Date(str);
    var exp = today.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - startDate.getMonth();
    return exp;
  };
```

Comment: https://s18.postimg.org/3l50bk8nt/debug.jpg

I tried that, but it does not execute the var diff= date.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

Please check screenshot for info

Comment: you are sending a date string into the function instead try sending date object

Comment: The error is ::

"[$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
                            {{getExp(employee.careerStartedOn)}}
                        
TypeError: startDate.getTime is not a function

Comment: @Phoenix I have updated the answer try now ! The error was because you are sending date as string object instead of date that is why there is no getTime () function .

Comment: Ok, I want the result to be converted to years/months/days to make it an exact amount. with this code days wont be calculated?

Comment: you can use the below answer by @Nishant for that just changing the function logic

Comment: Thanks a lot :) appreciate your time and effort.