# calculate date difference between two dates with angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to calculate date difference between two dates with angular js. I used this code:

```
$scope.formatString = function(format) {
    var year   = parseInt(format.substring(0,5));
    var month  = parseInt(format.substring(6,8));
    var day   = parseInt(format.substring(9,10));
    var date = new Date(year, month-1, day);
    return date;
}

$scope.dayDiff = function(fromdate,todate){
    var date2 = new Date($scope.formatString(fromdate));
    var date1 = new Date($scope.formatString(todate));
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());   
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    return diffDays;
}
```

But it is right for within same month but it can't do right calculation between two dates in different months.

- For example date1 = 2016.2.12, date2 = 2016.2.18 (Ok)
- For example date1 = 2016.2.12, date2 = 2016.3.1 (It is not right)

Comment: refer datediff filter given in - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635082/calculating-date-difference-with-angular-filter  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try using the String `split` function ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) to parse your date, split will produce an array of the year, month, and day in that order based on the format you're inputting.  From there you can reference the array pieces by index, a bit easier than trying to get your substring offsets lined up correctly:

```
$scope.formatString = function(format) {
  var pieces = format.split('.'),
      year   = parseInt(pieces[0]), 
      month  = parseInt(pieces[1]), 
      day    = parseInt(pieces[2]),
      date   = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

  return date;
}
```

Take a look at this working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/GgXjqA76IX5bzQEP56ux?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your helpfulness.This is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a ready-made library. Because you do not know that in the future you will still need to work with dates. I recommend [sugarjs](http://www.sugarjs.com).

The difference between the dates can be found in the following manner.

```
Date.range('2012.01.01', '2013.01.01').every('days').length
```