# How to calculate the difference between both time and date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Start time = 03/30/2017 15:55
End time = 03/31/2017 20:55

What I want is Elapsed time should be the difference between both start time and end time and it should display both the date and time.

Comment: Can you show us some code I mean what have you done so far?

Comment: https://github.com/christopher-weir/AngularJs-TimeDifference/blob/master/angular-timedifference.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635082/calculating-date-difference-with-angular-filter

Answer (score 0):

`date.parse` gives you the miliseconds (since 1970).
Just compare those numbers then. If its higher its a later date.

For more questions visit : https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse